# How to recover files lost copying to another harddrive with insufficient space

Tags: linux, files, data-recovery

This is yet another question on how to recover lost files. Still, I do not really know what happened that made me lose my files and can't find any help online. I will explain my situation:

I am using Linux Mint 20.2.
I have multiple hard drives installed and was copying something between them. `fdisk -l` outputs:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232,91 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5d4322fb

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 488396799 487344130 232,4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 488396799 487344128 232,4G 83 Linux




Disk /dev/sdb: 232,91 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 860 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8035f05f

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 488396799 488394752 232,9G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdc: 465,78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST500DM002-1BD14
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5a849229

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 976773119 976771072 465,8G 83 Linux
```

`sda` is my linux hard drive, and `sdb` and `sdc` are internal data drives with only files on them.

So today I plugged in my external harddrive (labeled "Backup" / `sdd`) which has NTFS filesystem. It's not shown in the `fdisk` output because I disconnected it. I was copying something from this harddrive and to this harddrive simultaneously.

I was copying the directory `data/raw` FROM `sdd` (Backup) TO the same folder on `sdc`. And I was copying the directory `data/projects` FROM `sdc` TO the same folder on `sdd` (the external Harddrive). I was doing this using the GUI file manager and drag and drop. I am pretty sure that I really did *copy* the files and not *move* them.

While I was doing this, an error popped up, that unfortunately, I clicked away too fast, not noticing what option I chose and what it said. My `sdc` internal harddrive was full after this so I assume the error said I do not have enough space left.

**PROBLEM**: After this error message, my **entire** `data` folder on the external hard drive was empty. I do not get why, as I was only copying from the subfolders of this directory in the two independent operations.

I tried to look in the trash folders of the external and internal harddrives, which were empty unfortunately. I also tried using `testdisk` but it doesn't find any problems or deleted files. I have also tried using `ntfsundelete` to no avail.

If I connect the external harddrive to a Windows system, it cannot open the `data` folder, telling me it is faulty.

So I do not really know what happened or if and how to get back my files. They are nowhere else in the system and seem completely gone. Luckily I have backups of most of it but still I would like to know what happened and if there is any chance to rescue the data.

**EDIT:** I thought about it some more. If, perhaps, I did a cut and not a copy, my harddrive ran out of space, and I would have clicked "try to copy anyway", could that have caused my data to become lost? But even if so, only the cut toward the full harddrive would be affected and not my whole data folder lost.

Comment: It is hard to say how - and if at all - you can recover from that situation, if you don't know what actually happened.

Comment: I understand. But within the different possible copy/pastes I did, would anything explain why my entire data folder is gone? I am just trying to understand what has happened and could have led to the data loss. I also find it weird that the folder is unreadable by Windows.